# How to maintain form values of previous form while moving forward to next form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a registration form that sends OTP after I click submit on the registration page.
It verifies OTP and then lets the user login with a verified email.
But if the user wants to go back and change some things and he goes back, the form values are auto-cleared so he has to fill the form all over again.
I want them to stay until OTP is not verified or the page is not reloaded. What is the best practice to handle these types of forms?

Registration.js

```
 const handleSubmit = async e => {
e.preventDefault();
setLoader(true);

const config = {
  header: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
try {
  const errors = validateUser();
  if (Object.keys(errors).length) {
    setFieldErrors(errors);
    setLoader(false);
    
    return;
  }

  const { data } = await axios.post(
    '/api/auth/registeration',

    {
      firstname,
      lastname,
      email,
      password
    },
    config
  );
  setTimeout(() => {
    setLoader(false);
    localStorage.setItem('authToken', data.token);

    toast.success(`Otp sent to ${formData.email}`, {
      theme: 'colored'
    });
    ///Putting email in state so otp verification page can access it
    navigate('/authentication/card/OtpVerification', { state: { email } });
  }, 1000);
  
} 
catch (error) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setLoader(false);
    setError(error.response.data.error);
    toast.info(`User already exist `, {
      theme: 'colored'
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      setError('Error');
    }, 5000);
  }, 1000);
}
};
```

otpverification.js

```
  ////Props.em has email
  if(props.em==undefined){
  navigate("/authentication/card/404");
 }
 const email=props.em;

  console.log(error || '');
 // Handler
 const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const config = {
  header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
 };
 try {

const { data } = await axios.post(
    "/api/auth/VerifyEmail",
    {otpPass,email},
    config
);
if(data){
  //do nothing
}
//localStorage.setItem("authToken",data.token);
toast.success(`Verified as ${email}`, {
  theme: 'colored'
});

navigate("/authentication/card/login");

}catch (error) {


setTimeout(() => {
  setError("bbn");
 }, 5000);
 } 


  };
```

Comment: How would the user be moving "back"? Maybe there's a better way, but if it's via a button you provide, your second form could store the first form's inputs in hidden fields, then your button would submit the 2nd form back to the first and fill in the values.

Comment: Like where should i save those values securely as it has password information as well.

Comment: You can store them in the global state before submitting to the server.

Comment: By 'back', do you mean browser's back, or programmatically back?

Comment: Password is one field I'd force them to re-type.

Comment: I know these things are really useful but what is the best practice,how should a registration form with OTP should be handled?

Comment: @AidHadzic Both ,He should see form values he entered if he goes back on browser or even through back button.

Comment: why can't you try store the details in a session storage